# How to change the value of check-boxes if checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the value of a check-box when I checked on them from 0-1

This is what I have tried

`HTML`

```
        <input type="checkbox" name="Semi Annual" id="1" value="0">
        Semi Annual <br>


        <input type="checkbox" name="Quaterly" id="2" value="0">
        Quaterly <br>


        <input type="checkbox" name="Monthly" id="3" value="0">
        Monthly <br>
```

`JS`

```
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
                 this.value = 1;
    });
```

Demo : http://codepen.io/evoque2015/pen/RNpOLq

Comment: What's the point of doing this? If a checkbox is unchecked, it won't be sent to the server when the containing form is posted. The only time the "value" attribute matters is when it's checked.

Comment: Your code is ok, you just forget to include jQuery library. look : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYeZvL

Comment: Always - **always!!** - have your browser console open while you're testing things. The fact that `$` was undefined would have been quite obvious.

Comment: So what do you suggest for alternative way for this ? I want to need to keep track of which box is checked, and which box is not, and based on that I can do something with it.

Comment: @evoque2015 ???? If a checkbox is checked, the `.checked` property will be `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/ne3979of/) does what you wanted to do by switching the value from 0 to 1 and vice versa depending on whether they are checked or not.

The each loop with logs demos that you don't actually need to do this.
The .checked property is already set to true or false by default onchange so you should just make use of this.

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Semi Annual" id="1" value="0">
        Semi Annual <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Quaterly" id="2" value="0">
        Quaterly <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Monthly" id="3" value="0">
        Monthly <br>
```

#### JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){

    // Changes value to 1 or 0 depending on whether it is checked or not
    if(this.value == 0){
        this.value = 1;
    }
    else{
        this.value = 0;  
    }

    // Log shows the value of each checkbox and also that the .checked property does the same thing by default
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, element){
        if(element.checked){
            console.log(this.name + ' has value of ' + this.value);
            console.log(this.name + ' is checked');   
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.name + ' has value of ' + this.value);
            console.log(this.name + ' is not checked');             
        }
    });
});
```